# Worked on Python 2.7 but not on 3.4 - Dictionaries. List indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary, nameerror

I have this problem: When I try to print out average grade of my class it gives me "indices must be integers not str" error.

`def average` works fine but second one `average_class`...

I add that this code works fine in codecademy 2.7 version course (not exactly the same code)

How can I run this on my 3.4 python version ?? :)

```
przemyslaw = {
   "name": "Przemyslaw",
   "homework": [4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4],
   "shorttests": [2, 4, 2],
   "tests": [4, 4, 3, 5]
   }

magdalena = {
   "name": "Magdalena",
   "homework": [5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4],
   "shorttests": [4, 5, 5],
   "tests": [5, 5, 4, 5]
   }

def average(student):
   homework = average_sub(student["homework"])
   shorttests = average_sub(student["shorttests"])
   tests = average_sub(student["tests"])
   average = tests * 0.6 + shorttests * 0.3 + homework * 0.1
   return float(average)

def average_class(students):
   total = []
   for loop in students:
       total.append(average(loop))
   return average(total)

print(average_class([magdalena, przemyslaw]))
```

Comment: your problem is `return average(total)` since `total` is a list, not a dict like you expect the `average` function to take in (specifically, a dict with keys `"homework"` and `"shorttests"`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
def average_class(students):
    total = []
    for loop in students:
        total.append(average(loop))
    return average(total)
```

into:

```
def average_class(students):
    total = []
    for loop in students:
        total.append(average(loop))
    return average_sub(total)
```

The only difference is the last line. This should work with Python 2 and 3.